# Erro: Deploy Python Heroku - runtime (python-3.4.0) is not available

Tags: python-3.x, django, deploy, heroku, django-2.0

Pesoal,
tudo bem.

Alguém consegue me ajudar na solução do seguinte problema:

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em Django e agora estou no processo de realizar o envio para o servidor. Vou enviar para o Heroku.

Realizei os seguintes comandos:

Criando repositório git:

```
$ git init
```

Adiciona e "commitando" no repositório iniciado:

```
$ git add .

$ git commit -m "first commit"
```

Logo após:

```
$ heroku create

$ git push -m master
```

E o seguinte erro acontece:

```
Counting objects: 97, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (85/85), done.
Writing objects: 100% (97/97), 324.35 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 97 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Requested runtime (python-3.5.2) is not available for this stack (heroku-18).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to polar-reaches-18114.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/polar-reaches-18114.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/polar-reaches-18114.git'
```

Então, estou fazendo o deploy acompanhando uma vídeo aula e na época o professor estava utilizando o python 3.4.0, porém atualmente estou utilizando o python 3.5.2, vendo isso, inclui no arquivo runtime.txt: pyhton-3.5.2. Porém pelo que entendi da mensagem a versão do python não está sendo reconhecida, tentei também realizar o mesmo processo alterando a descrição do arquivo runtime.txt para python-3.4.0, porém ocorre o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação do Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support) eles apenas suportam as versões 3.7.1, 3.6.7 e 2.7.15 do Python. Você está tentando usar versões que não estão mais disponíveis, assim, modifique seu projeto para utilizar a versão 3.7.1 (recomendável) ou 3.6.7 que funcionará.

Comment: Obrigado! Estou só encontrando tutoriais de instalação da versão do Python 3.7.0. Consegue me informar como consigo instalar a versão 3.7.1?

Comment: Verifiquei que existe tutoriais para a versão python 3.6.6 que segundo a [documentação do Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support) é a versão default: "By default, newly created Python apps use the python-3.6.6 runtime.". Vou tentar instalar a versão python 3.6.6